# Is there a Darcs Plugin for Hudson

Tags: plugins, hudson, version-control, darcs

Hy,
I want to use [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) together with [darcs](http://www.darcs.net) (a scm).

**Is there a plugin which adds Darcs-Support to Hudson?** I found no reference on the [Pluginlist](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Plugins#Plugins-Sourcecodemanagement) of Hudson, so has anybody found a plugin? I know I could write my own plugin but if somebody else has done this already I can save the time...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, Darcs isn't supported so far by Hudson. So you have 3 options:

- Use another supported SCM
- Use another Continuous Integration server with Darcs support (e.g. Cruise Control)
- Implement an Hudson plugin for Darcs :)

Comment: Thanks, but Cruise Control offers less comfort as you have to write the project-definition from scratch and not using a web-gui. But its an alternative, you're right!

Answer (score 2):

I just began to play around with Java. I try to make a Darcs plugin for Hudson. You can join on [GitHub](https://github.com/Weltraumschaf/darcs-plugin).

Comment: I just finished version 0.2.2 of [hudson-darcs](https://github.com/Weltraumschaf/hudson-darcs) plugin. It checks out a repo and make change viewable (file add, remove, modify and move) in hudson builds and project summary. I work hard on getting it unittested abd integration of [darcsweb](http://blitiri.com.ar/p/darcsweb/).

Answer (score 2):

There is a newly developed darcs plugin for hudson/jenkins. See the [darcs plugin homepage](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Darcs+Plugin).

Answer (score 1):

Buildbot comes with darcs support: http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/current/Darcs.html#Darcs

Answer (score 0):

There is no Darcs plugin for Hudson.